# Удалённый вызов метода

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Допустим у меня есть приложение на c# со следующим кодом:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Example2
{
 class Program
{
    public static void Hello()

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {     
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Как с помощью Reflection вызвать метод Hello() из другого приложения (разумеется тоже на c#)??

Comment: Если кратко то как то так: Assembly.LoadFile \ assembly.GetType \ type.GetMethod \ Activator.CreateInstance(type) \ method.Invoke

Comment: "Удаленный" вызов не совсем удачное название темы потому что подразумевает что то типа RPC (remote procedure call) - вызов через сеть. Здесь скорее подойдет слово "динамический" вызов.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас есть сборка этой программы, то вы можете добавить ссылку на нее к приложению, которое должно вызывать метод Hello и вызывть этот метод напрямую без всяческих колдунств с рефлексией, так как метод Hello у вас открытый, да еще и статический (то есть нет необходимости создавать экземпляр класса Program)

Если же доступа к этой сборке нет, то вы не сможете вызвать метод ни с рефлексией, ни без нее

Comment: Для плагинов рефлексия предпочтительнее.

Comment: @cpp_user в вопросе нигде не говорилось о плагинах

Comment: Это пример тому почему ему нужна именно рефлексия.

Comment: @cpp_user: Для плагинов предпочтительнее [встроенная в BCL поддержка плагинов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145020%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: @cpp_user практически всегда нормальный вызов метода предпочтительнее, нежели рефлексия в силу разных причин, начиная от производительности и заканчивая опасностью получить исключение в рантайме в случае, если имя метода, пространства имен или сборки указано неверно. Если у автора вопроса есть какие-то веские причины использовать именно рефлексию, а не обычный вызов метода, то имеет смысл это указать , но и тогда  весьма возможно, что использование рефлексии  вовсе не оправдано.

Comment: Это сугубо в образовательных целях, вот исходный код решения, может кому-то пригодится:

Comment: Это все понятно но случаев когда нужна именно рефлексия вагон и маленькая тележка.

Answer (score 1):

Для случая, когда у вас сборка Example2.exe лежит в каталоге основной программы, подойдёт такой код:

```
var assemblyPartialName = "Example2";
var asm = Assembly.Load(assemblyPartialName);
var type = asm.GetType("Example2.Program");
var method = type.GetMethod("Hello");
method.Invoke(null, null);
```

(заметьте, что разницы между exe и dll нет: с точки зрения `Assembly.Load` и то и то — сборка.)

Для случая, когда сборка лежит в другом каталоге, лучше делать так:

```
var assemblyPath = @"path\to\Example2.exe";
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
var type = asm.GetType("Example2.Program");
var method = type.GetMethod("Hello");
method.Invoke(null, null);
```

При этом будут загружены все зависимости `Example2`, лежащие в том же каталоге. Учтите, что этот вариант может быть не тем, что вам нужно, т. к. типы, загруженные в контексте `LoadFrom`, несовместимы с типами, загруженными в контексте `Load`. (Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Choosing a Binding Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx).)

С другой стороны, если путь, где будет лежать `Example2.exe`, известен при компиляции, может оказаться достаточным (при отсутствии конфликтов зависимостей) установить [`app.config/probing` path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element), чтобы он включал путь к `Example2.exe`, и пользоваться `Load`.

Грузить сборку, прочитав её как массив байт в память — плохая идея. Не говоря уже о напрасном расходе памяти, подумайте, откуда .NET будет грузить *зависимости* вашей загружаемой сборки?

---

Есть ещё вариант `LoadFile`, но он [ещё хуже, чем `LoadFrom`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/suzcook/loadfile-vs-loadfrom), требует подписаться на `AssemblyResolve` для загрузки зависимостей, и нужен только в особых случаях — например, если вы почему-либо хотите загрузить одновременно две разные версии одной и той же сборки.

Comment: Мой код загружает в память выбранный файл, ищет в нем метод Hello() и выполняет его у себя, а можно провернуть следующую авантюру?: 1) Предположим что та программа в которой я беру этот метод запущена 2) Могу ли я заставить её выполнить этот метод в ней же??

Comment: @Dagger: В принципе, да. Но это намного сложнее.

Comment: Не только сложнее но и не безопасно, так как метод может быть не thread safe.

Comment: @Dagger: Для этого надо создать отдельный поток в приложении ([`CreateRemoveThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) и в этом потоке уже что-то делать. Вот, например, как это делает snoop (он инжектит Window Hook, правда): http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ManagedInjector/Injector.cpp

Comment: Благодарю, господа.

Comment: @Dagger: Например, как-то так: http://www.cyberforum.ru/post4516796.html. А в dll должен быть код на C++/CLI. (Потому что нужен сишный entry point.)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("d:\\example.exe"));
        Type t = asm.GetType("Example2.Program");
        MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Hello");
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        method.Invoke(obj, null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```