# Как задать структуру выходного проекта?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

По умолчанию VS при компиляции кладет все в одну директорию рядом с EXE.

Т.е и сборки и все остальное лежат в одной папке.

Как создать свою собственную структуру?

Например, я хочу, что бы одни сборки клались в одну папку, другие в другую, а в корне был EXE.

Comment: Но так ваш exe не стартует. Попробуйте сами перенести вручную DLL в другие каталоги.

Comment: Копируйте в подпапку либы, а стандартное поведение по копированию либ к ехе - отключите. Плюс, напишите в ехе резолв сборок с учетом того, что надо искать в подпапках.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну это как бы можно[.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow4sh.jpg)

Для начала, вы добавляете каталоги, в которых будут лежать ваши библиотеки, в assembly probing path. Для этого отредактируйте ваш app.config, добавьте в него следующее:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="some\subfolder;another\subfolder"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

([Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location).)

Затем, в свойствах проекта в зависимостях укажите CopyLocal = False:

[image: copy local]

Затем, в свойствах проекта-библиотеки установите Output Path в каталог, где вы хотите получить эту DLL (для каждого из ваших target platform/processor):

[image: целевой подкаталог]

Ну или в post-build step каждого из зависимых проектов укажите вручную копирование куда надо.

Всё, должно работать.

---

Как [советует @Andrew B в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574203/#comment756966_574211), существует ещё один путь, описанный в [документации](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/837908): подписаться на событие `AssemblyResolve`, которое отправляется, если .NET не может загрузить сборку из вашего каталога.

Для этого нужен код наподобие такого:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
```

где метод `OnAssemblyResolve` определён так:

```
Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(","));

    // проверка на то, есть ли загружаемая сборка среди наших статических ссылок
    // взята из https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/837908
    // но вам может быть и не нужна, подумайте сами
    if (!Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
                 .Any(asmName => asmName.FullName.Substring(0, asmName.FullName.IndexOf(","))
                                    == name))
    {
        // это не assembly из наших ссылок
        return null;
    }

    var applicationDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    foreach (var subfolder in new[] { @"some\subfolder", @"another\subfolder" })
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(applicationDir, subfolder, name + ".dll";
        if (File.Exists(path))
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }

    return null;
}
```

(Не тестировал.)

Достоинство этого решения — то, что список путей можно изменять динамически, если это вдруг понадобилось.

Недостаток — то, что у вас некоторые сборки [будут грузиться в assembly binding-контексте `LoadFrom`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/) в отличие от обычной загрузки в контексте `Load`. Типы, загруженные в таком контексте, будут несовместимы с типами, загруженными в обычном контексте. Особенно это может «клюнуть», если у вас в разных местах лежат разные версии одной и той же сборки. [Это может привести к эффекту, когда один и тот же статический класс существует в двух экземплярах.] Будьте осторожны и готовы к неожиданностям! (Вопрос также обсуждался [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435205/10105).)

Если ваши сборки приходят с ресурсами, возможно, вам нужно учесть [эту модификацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23238712/276994).

Дополнительное чтение по теме assembly binding/load context:

- [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx)
- [Suzanne Cook, `LoadFile` vs. `LoadFrom`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom/)

---

Для автоматического копирования сборок в целевые каталоги посредством MSBuild посмотрите ответы к [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119271/276994).

Но в целом, я бы порекомендовал воспользоваться [советом @TomTom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2445590/276994) и не заморачиваться, а оставить всё как есть. То, что файлы лежат в одном каталоге, пользователь не увидит, если вы правильным образом поместите ярлыки в системное меню при инсталляции (а вы в любом случае должны это сделать).

Comment: а что такое _assembly probing path_?

Comment: @Grundy: Это то, где .NET будет искать подключаемые сборки. Пo умолчанию — каталог программы и GAC.

Comment: Ну я имел ввиду, как в него добавлять? это где-то в настройках? или то что сами структуру итоговую делаем?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, у васй же в проекте есть файл app.config, вот прям в него.

Comment: ааа, это я в конфиге не увидел элемента _probing_, думал это что-от еще где-то

Comment: Посмотрите эту статью. Возможно, она будет полезной [support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/837908](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/837908)

Comment: @AndrewB: Да, я знаю эту статью, спасибо. Решение с GAC — не то, что хочет ТС. Указывать codebase муторно, там нужны все assembly с точной версией. А путь через AssemblyResolve слишком сложный, ну и в таком тонком коде можно случайно и ошибиться.

Comment: @VladD, я предложил ее, т.к., возможно, часть материала статьи можно было бы добавить в ответ, чтобы сделать его более полным.

Comment: А можно в рантайме задать эту настройку, а не в app.config?

Comment: @Monk: Нет, в рантайме только через AssemblyResolveEvent

Comment: При использовании Assembly.LoadFrom можно наткнуться на очень неприятную фичу под названием Load-From Context -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, неподготовленному человеку будет тяжело понять, что же идет не так.  Стоит упомянуть об этом в ответе.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ага, у меня даже где-то был ответ по этому поводу :)

Comment: @VladD существует такая штука как метаданные DestinationSubDirectory у элемента ReferenceCopyLocalPaths - их можно использовать чтобы положить все зависимости в другую директорию. Но я не пробовал класть разные зависимости в разные директории...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Прикольно, не знал. А оно и подзависимости транзитивно положит туда же?

Comment: @VladD да. Собственно, элемент ReferenceCopyLocalPaths - это и есть любая зависимость, включая транзитивную.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Понял, спасибо!