# Позднее связывание с использованием сборки, которая имеет зависимости

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, имеется сборка, а у этой сборки в свою очередь есть зависимости от других сборок, которые лежат в определенном месте.

Имеются следующие вопросы:

1. С подобными сборками можно работать только через `AppDomain`, а обычный `Assembly.Load` не сработает?
2. Порядок загрузки сборок в `AppDomain` имеет значение? Например, загрузить сборку, которая имеет зависимости первой.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу первой части вопроса: работает. Сошлюсь на [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574211/10105), тут расписано достаточно подробно.

---

По поводу второй части вопроса, если все сборки грузятся через `Assembly.Load`, то разницы нет.

Если же, например, сборка `A` грузится через `LoadFrom`, то если другая сборка с тем же именем `A` грузится через `Load` (или есть в зависимостях у ещё какой-то сборки, грузящейся через `Load`), то возможны проблемы с тем, что сборка не будет найдена, или неожиданные `InvalidCastException`'ы, или просто будет выдана уже загруженная версия сборки вместо нужной. Или если сборка с тем же именем `A` была загружена раньше через `Load`, может быть возвращена уже загруженная сборка. В этом случае порядок загрузки имеет значение.

Информация взята тут: [Suzanne Cook, Choosing a Binding Context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/) и тут: [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx).