# Как встроить 7z.dll в exe?

Tags: c#, dll, embedded

args.Name Почему-то содержит = "Project_file_backup.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=ru-RU, PublicKeyToken=null"

И всегда: return null:

```
static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.StartsWith("7z"))
        {
            return Assembly.Load(Project1.Properties.Resources._7z);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

var a = Assembly.Load(Project1.Properties.Resources._7z);           
SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine("", a.FullName));
```

> {"Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку \"1073664 bytes loaded from
>   Project_file_backup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null\" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана
>   попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат."}
>
> System.BadImageFormatException не обработано   FileName=1073664 bytes
>   loaded from Project_file_backup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null   FusionLog=""   HResult=-2147024885   Message=Не
>   удалось загрузить файл или сборку "1073664 bytes loaded from
>   Project_file_backup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана
>   попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          в System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadImage(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence evidence, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean fIntrospection, SecurityContextSource
>   securityContextSource)
>          в System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[] rawAssembly)
>          в MyProcess.FileBackup.AddToArchive2(String[] fileNames, String archiveName) 
>   ...
>          в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2147024885
>          Message=Неправильный формат IL.
>          InnerException:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант2

```
public static void Load(string name)
    {
        String resourceName = "app1." +
        new AssemblyName(name).Name + ".dll";
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    }
```

...

```
        Load(@"Resources\7z.dll");

        //var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        //SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"Resources\7z.dll"));

        SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, ???Что здесь писать?));
        //???Что здесь писать
```

Смотрю как делают здесь:

http://www.sql.ru/forum/868852/kak-sdelat-takoy-appdomain-currentdomain-assemblyresolve

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/#comments

http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/433016d1410669282

Comment: Ну то есть это можно, если загрузить через какое-нибудь `Assembly.Load(byte[])`, но это довольно сложно. А зачем это вам, если не секрет?

Comment: чтобы библиотеки не устанаставить в систему. При использовании рядом лежащего Resources\7z.dll при некоторых запусках через другой exe или ярлык или от другого пользователя ненаходит Resources\7z. 2) Использовать один файл удобней.

Comment: А почему именно в Resources, а не прямо в тот же каталог?

Comment: В visual studio файл был загружен из 7-zip автоматически в Resources.
А что есть разница?

Comment: Ещё какая! http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574203/10105 А каким образом вы загрузили его? Это надо постараться, чтобы файл попал в каталог Resources. Обычно нужно добавлять через References -> AddReference.

Comment: Это нормально, что в коде **7z,** , а не **7z.** ?

Comment: int3 исправил но ошибка осталась

Comment: VladD не добавляется как ссылка

Comment: Проблема скорее всего не во встраивании а в указании пути `SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath`...я помню ваш предыдущий вопрос - не было времени посмотреть. С этой библой не работал - без этого метода никак нельзя обойтись?