# Изменить путь до используемых dll

Tags: c#

Подскажите как изменить путь до dll, чтобы программа искала не в каталоге ,в которой лежит сама программа а например путь до программы + "\bin\libs"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574203/10105

Comment: @VladD мне нужно чтобы при запуске искала dll для своей работы по пути путь до программы + "\bin\libs"

Comment: Ну да, тот ответ именно об этом.

Comment: @VladD что-то не работает - прописал <probing privatePath="rust_server_Data\Managed\Client"/> но все равно dll берет из папки,где программа

Comment: А если удалить DLL из каталога программы? Документация врать не должна.

Comment: Подождите, а у вас вообще есть app.config? Или у вас ASP.NET?

Comment: @VladD С#.Если удалить из папки с программой - крашит https://c.radikal.ru/c05/1801/0b/037368ad7ce8.png

Comment: А можно картинку в вопрос? А то у меня radikal.ru на работе заблокирован. Да и для остальных участников будет проще.

Comment: @VladD закрепил

Comment: А в каком каталоге у вас находится `rust_server_Data`? В `bin\Debug` или нет? Мой миелофон говорит, что вы не настроили копирование.

Comment: @VladD exe я помешаю в папку Main - там дальше есть путь rust_server_Data\Managed\Client - нужно чтобы оттуда брало dll для работы,а не из самой папки с программой

Comment: @VladD ************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Не удается найти указанный файл.
File name: 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Comment: @VladD вот D:\Main\rust_server_Data\Managed\Client

Comment: Тогда вы, очевидно, забыли скопировать RustAlphaV2-server.exe.config?

Comment: @VladD точно - спасибо.А можно как нибудь без него?А то лишние файлы не к чему

Comment: Без него никак, боюсь. Окей, тогда я закрываю вопрос как дубликат.

Comment: Если лишние файлы ни к чему, тогда идёте в корень диска, жмёте Ctrl+A, Shift+Del. Зачем столько файлов на диске, нэ?