# Как правильно вызвать метод, использующий ссылку, через рефлексию?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Извините, не придумал как лучше сформулировать вопрос. 
Разбираюсь с рефлексией. У меня свой велосипед псевдо-WAMP протокола=) Хочу удаленно вызывать методы посредством RPC. И раз уж разбираюсь с рефлексией, хочу сделать приложение расширяемым. Т.е. что бы в дальнейшем я мог просто написать библиотеку-плагин. Кинуть его в папку с wamp-сервером и использовать удаленно.

Собственно, проблема возникла когда я в своей библиотеке использую ссылку на какую-нибудь другую библиотеку. Сервер вторую библиотеку само собой не видит, а потому метод из моей библиотеки выполнить не может.

Как помимо моей библиотеки подключить еще и те, на которые моя ссылается?

Метод, который есть сейчас:

```
private string CallInvoke(WebSocketSession session, Call call)
        {
            try
            {
                string filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Plugins/" + call.PluginFileName;

                //Если файл плагина не найден
                if (!File.Exists(filepath))
                {
                    CallError callError = new CallError(call.CallId, "Plugin file not found.\r\n(" + filepath + ")");
                    return JsonSerialize(callError);
                }
                Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(filepath);
                Type _class = null;
                MethodInfo _method = null;

                var types = asm.GetTypes();

                //Если в плагине нет нужного класса
                if (types.Count(x => x.Name == call.ClassName) == 0)
                {
                    CallError callError = new CallError(call.CallId, "Class \"" + call.ClassName + "\" not found in assembly \"" + asm.FullName + "\".");
                    return JsonSerialize(callError);
                }

                _class = types.Single(x => x.Name == call.ClassName);

                var methodInfos = _class.GetMethods();

                //Если в классе нет нужного метода
                if (methodInfos.Count(x => x.Name == call.MethodName) == 0)
                {
                    CallError callError = new CallError(call.CallId, "Method \"" + call.MethodName + "\" not found in class \"" + call.ClassName + "\".");
                    return JsonSerialize(callError);
                }

                _method = methodInfos.Single(x => x.Name == call.MethodName);

                object result = null;

                if (call.Params is null)
                    result = _method.Invoke(null, null);
                else
                    result = _method.Invoke(null, new object[] { call.Params });

                CallResult callResult = new CallResult(call.CallId, result);
                return JsonSerialize(callResult);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                CallError callError = new CallError(call.CallId, ex.Message);
                return JsonSerialize(callError);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET не видит зависимую библиотеку потому, что она не находится в каталоге приложения.

Самый простой метод — положить плагины со всеми зависимостями прямо в каталог приложения, и не париться. И грузить сборки через `Assembly.Load`, это самый правильный путь. Если очень-очень хочется, можно установить assembly probing path в app.config:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="Plugins"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

(и всё равно использовать `Assembly.Load`).

Более подробно здесь: [Как задать структуру выходного проекта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574203/10105)

Comment: Не совсем то. Суть плагинов в том, что бы не перекомпиливать основной проект под каждый плагин.

Comment: Нашел такую штуку: Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies(). Я не совсем понимаю, как их использовать. После подгрузки сборки, нужно ее как-то указать вызываемому методу? Или она просто висит в памяти до востребованности?

Comment: @АлександрЛи: А почему не то? Что именно не подходит?

Comment: Потому, что придется перекомпилировать основной проект всякий раз, когда захочу добавить плагин, использующий новую библиотеку. Или нет?

Comment: @АлександрЛи: По идее нет, вы можете завести по Solution'у для каждого плагина, если хотите.