# Как указать место расположения включаемой dll

Tags: c++-cli

### Как переместить включаемую библиотеку .dll в другой каталог?

Для работы с MySQL базой необходима библиотека, которую я подключаю в ссылках проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в итоге, при компиляции, я получаю **.exe** файл и эту библиотеку в том же катологе что и **.ехе** файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить Visual Studio класть при создании эту библиотеку в другой каталог, скажем **\Config**, который будет лежать в том же катологе что и создаваемый **.ехе** файл?
Если эту **.dll** удалить, то приложение отказывается запускаться совсем..

Нашел [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574203/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0) на свой вопрос, вот только для **С#**. Где искать эти настройки в **C++ cli**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- В папках Debug и Release, в которые происходит компиляция проекта, создаём папку Config, в которой будут храниться библиотеки. Эти папки находятся в каталоге солюшена, где лежит файл `*.sln`.

- Открываем свойства библиотеки. В разделе Configuration Properties > General ищем пункт Output Directory. Там должно быть `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)`. Меняем на `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\Config` - то есть добавляем путь до искомой папки.

- В главном проекте выбираем прилинкованную библиотеку и в её свойствах задаём Copy Local = false.

- Добавляем в проект файл app.config. Add New Item > Utility > Configuration file. В нём добавляем:

  ```xml
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Config"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  ```

  В атрибуте `privatePath` - относительный пункт к нашей папке.

- В свойствах главного проекта в разделе Build Events > Post-Build Event пишем в Command Line:

  ```xml
  copy app.config "$(TargetPath).config"
  ```

  Эта команда будет копировать конфиг с нужным именем в папку с exe-файлом.

Готово! Проект должен работать.

Comment: В итоге, в папке Release создается автоматом папка Config и приложение копируется туда.. а библиотеки нигде нет.. и приложение, соответственно, не работает..

Comment: Если руками в папку config положить эту библиотеку, то начинает работать, но в директории приложения должен находиться новый созданный файл с настройками приложения. В итоге, шило на мыло.

Comment: @Григорий - дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

- Создаём папку Config, в которой будут храниться библиотеки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Открываем свойства библиотеки. В разделе Configuration Properties >
  General ищем пункт Output Directory. Там должно быть
  $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration). Меняем на
  $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\Config - то есть добавляем путь до
  искомой папки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- В главном проекте выбираем прилинкованную библиотеку и в её свойствах
  задаём Copy Local = false.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Добавляем в проект файл app.config. Add New Item > Utility >
  Configuration file. В нём добавляем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- В свойствах главного проекта в разделе Build Events > Post-Build Event пишем в Command Line:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### В ИТОГЕ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге, в папке Release создается автоматом папка Config и приложение копируется туда.. а библиотеки нигде нет.. и приложение, соответственно, не работает..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Второй пункт - задание выходного каталога - его нужно изменить у _библиотеки_ (dll), а не у экзешника.

Comment: Все правильно, спасибо. Вот только библиотека не моя и ее проекта у меня нет, в свойствах которого это надо сделать.

Comment: Если библиотека не ваша, просто положите её в нужную папку и всё. Описанный процесс нужен тогда, когда работа над библиотекой продолжается: при каждой её сборке создаётся свежая версия в нужном каталоге.

Comment: Плюсанул, так как скриншоты - это хорошо. Помогут тем, кто столкнётся с похожей проблемой.

Comment: Спасибо. Я изначально и пытался эту библиотеку из папки где лежит приложение спрятать в папку config, что, как я понял, невозможно если библиотека чужая.